# Dictionary of type [NSObject: AnyObject] has no member "value(forKeyPath: ...)"

Tags: ios, swift3, anyobject

I'm converting an app to swift3 and encountering the following problem.

```
@objc required init(response: HTTPURLResponse, representation: [NSObject : AnyObject])
{
    if (representation.value(forKeyPath: "title") is String)    {
        self.title = **representation.value**(forKeyPath: "title") as! String
    }
```

I get the following error:

> Value of type [NSObject:AnyObject] has no member value.

In the old version of the code I was just using AnyObject as type for representation, but if I do so I get the error `AnyObject is not a subtype of NSObject` there:

```
if (representation.value(forKeyPath: "foo") is String) {
    let elementObj = Element(response: response, representation:**representation.value(forKeyPath: "foo")**!)
}
```

Comment: `NSObject` and `(forKeyPath: "title")` won't go well. Is it possible to use `[String : AnyObject]`?

Comment: why not simply `self.title = representation["title"]`?

Comment: Do you really know what the method `value(forKeyPath:` is supposed to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing Objective-C and Swift styles. Better to actually decide.

Bridging back to `NSDictionary` is not automatic.

Consider:

```
let y: [NSObject: AnyObject] = ["foo" as NSString: 3 as AnyObject] // this is awkward, mixing Swift Dictionary with explicit types yet using an Obj-C type inside
let z: NSDictionary = ["foo": 3]
(y as NSDictionary).value(forKeyPath: "foo") // 3
// y["foo"] // error, y's keys are explicitly typed as NSObject; reverse bridging String -> NSObject/NSString is not automatic
y["foo" as NSString] // 3
y["foo" as NSString] is Int // true
z["foo"] // Bridging here is automatic though because NSDictionary is untyped leaving compiler freedom to adapt your values
z["foo"] is Int // true
// y.value // error, not defined

// Easiest of all:
let ynot = ["foo": 3]
ynot["foo"] // Introductory swift, no casting needed
ynot["foo"] is Int // Error, type is known at compile time
```

Reference:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html

Note the explicit use of `'as'` required to get a `String` back to `NSString`. Bridging is not hidden because they want you to use value types (`String`) over reference types (`NSString`). So this is deliberately more cumbersome.

> One of the primary advantages of value types over reference types is
>   that they make it easier to reason about your code. For more
>   information about value types, see Classes and Structures in The Swift
>   Programming Language (Swift 3), and WWDC 2015 session 414 Building
>   Better Apps with Value Types in Swift.